# Why is my C# constructor not working with the method I'm trying to use?

Tags: c#, class-constructors

Maybe I've misunderstood how constructors work, but in any case, I'm trying to create an array and populate it in the constructor.

I have the following code --

```
class ClsDeck
{
    private string[] deck = new string[52];
    private string[] hand = new string[12];
    BuildDeck()
    {
        //lots of code assigning images to each individual element of the "deck" array.
    }

    //many other methods that need to be called by a form.
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 insists that the method have a return type. I have simply added "void" to the BuildDeck method, and the error disappeared, but every example I've seen of a constructor has to have the same name as the class, and it has been the only method in the class.

Comment: That's not a constructor - it has to have the same name as the class.

Comment: Adding the void fixes the problem because you've then declared a method, not a constructor.

Comment: IMHO the down votes are not warranted.  This is a perfectly reasonable beginner question.  Each of us started somewhere.  It should however be closed as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 8):

That won't even compile. `BuildDeck()` has no return type. Constructor names need to match the class name (including case). Replace `BuildDeck` with `ClsDeck()`.

Comment: `and it has been the only method in the class` This is not usually the case.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a constructor is a method that 1.) has the same name as the class, and 2.) has no return value.

In your example above, "BuildDeck" is not a constructor ... it is a method, and therefore must specify a return type (or "void" if it doesn't return anything).

If you want a constructor, rename "BuildDeck" to "ClsDeck".

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of your class is actually missing.

Make the following changes, and your code will compile:

```
class ClsDeck
{
    private string[] deck = new string[52];
    private string[] hand = new string[12];

    public ClsDeck()
    {
        // Place your array initializations here.
    }

    private void BuildDeck()
    {
        //lots of code assigning images to each individual element of the "deck" array. }
        //many other methods that need to be called by a form.
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, the constructor of the class is inserted by the compiler :-)  Default constructor with an empty body.

Answer (score 2):

That will not work or compile. In order to achieve what you want, you could have a constructor for `ClsDeck`  and call `BuildDeck`

```
class ClsDeck {
    private string[] deck = new string[52];
    private string[] hand = new string[12];
    ClsDeck() { //lots of code assigning images to each individual element of the "deck" array. }

        //many other methods that need to be called by a form.
        BuildDeck();
    }

    private void BuildDeck() {
        //Build your deck
    }
}
```